# Why call a major second a diminished third?

Tags: theory, terminology, intervals

In the Hungarian minor scale we have the following intervals, expressed here in semitones, between the scale's notes (I to VIII):

```
I       II      III     IV      V       VI      VII     (I) / VIII
    2       1       3       1       1       3       1
```

If we take the C note as the base, we have:

```
c       d       d#      f#      g       ab      b       c
    2       1       3       1       1       3       1
```

If we take the trichord starting at position 4, [F♯, A♭, C], we have a chord consisting of a major second (F♯ to A♭: 2 semitones) and a major third (A♭ to C: 4 semitones).

I've been told that this major second is actually considered to be a diminished third. What is the reason for not calling it a major second? Why not accept this chord as the secundal-tertian hybrid it seems to be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a heptatonic scale, the interval between an arbitrary note and the note that is two steps further in the scale is always a third. The interval between any two adjacent notes is a second, and two seconds always make a third.

You wrote it yourself: it's the interval between F# and Ab. If it were a second, the Ab should be a G#. But the rule is that in a heptatonic scale, you get each note name (and its alteration) only once. That's also why you don't have a D# (as you wrote) but an Eb in the C Hungarian minor scale:

`C D Eb F# G Ab B`

Comment: Good catch - D#=Eb.

Answer (score 12):

It's because an interval is a measurement that is dependent on two parameters the letter distance between two notes and the semitones distance between two notes.

Any F to any A must be some kind of 3rd because the letter distance is that of a third. The quality of the 3rd is determined by the distance in semitones For F♯ to A♭ since the distance is 1 lower than a minor 3rd the resulting interval is a diminished 3rd. The naming schema of specific internals and the generalities of are shown in [this answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/41279/7222).

Spelling matters greatly in music which is why intervals take letter name into account and [this question and answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/23976/7222) go more into depth on why it matters.

Answer (score 2):

In most microtonal temperaments, a diminished 3rd is not the same as a major second. For example, in 19 equal temperament, a major second is 3 steps, and a diminished third is 4 steps.

Comment: How does this relate to the Hungarian minor scale?