# Origin of the distinction between major/minor, perfect intervals in light of the major second

Tags: theory, intervals

in short i have the following question: 
What is the historical/scientific reason behind the naming convention of major/minor second instead of naming the major second "*perfect*" second?

More specific:
I am aware that minor/major means different things for intervals and scales. As far as i got it the following is correct:

- All intervals in a major scale are either perfect or major
- A minor interval is equal to its major counterpart with the highest note being lowered by a semitone (so it is one semitone smaller)
- This does **not** imply that all intervals in a natural minor key are either minor or perfect

However it is also true that all except the second interval in a natural minor scale (which is a major second) are minor intervals or perfect (prime,octave,fourth,fifth are perfect; third, sixth, seventh are minor).
To me this seems a little bit arbitrary.

What is the scientific/historical reason for this? Is there any material you could recommend to help me understand how this came up?

All i could find in standard music theory textbooks is definitions that completely ignore the fact that this is not a very intuitive way of naming the second interval. I figured it might have something to do with the order of overtones in the overtone series but also was not able to find something specific.

Also i found this (somehow related) question by another user:
[Confusion about major and minor second intervals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/30401/confusion-about-major-and-minor-second-intervals/30434)
but it did not answer my question (it seems there was just some confusion about the major/minor terminology for scales and intervals)

P.S.: I learned music theory mainly in german language where many things have slightly different names. If something is unclear it might be a translation error so just let me know and i will try to clarify things.

Thank you for reading. I would highly appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Oh thank you very much the first two links https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22525/what-makes-an-interval-perfect and https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/41278/why-is-a-major-second-not-called-a-perfect-second were very interesting and helped me a lot. The third link (that i also linked in my original post) does not really answer my question though. However thank you that was very helpful.

Comment: I'll remove the 3rd one then.